# how to get all user allowed access in group access and user access cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

I've made group access and user access in cakephp ( access control list ), and all working as well as I wish, and now I have to get all user that have an access in a method.

my question is how can i get all user who are allowed in a method cakephp

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add more details with some code

Comment: I really don't know how to start this, so I don't have any code, or do you have tutorial or reference for me to try it first ?@tarikul05

Comment: then your can follow https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists--net-13457